# How can use socket correctly with angular4

Tags: angular, sockets

HOw can I using socket in angular4 . I want When user login , server emit user to client , but I can get user in client . Here is my code :

Socket service

```
@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  private socket;
  private url : string = 'http://localhost:2912';
  constructor() {
  } 

  init(){
    console.log('runnig')
     this.socket = io(this.url)
     this.socket.on('user',(user)=>{
       console.log('init',user) //I cant log user in here 
     })
  }

  getListUser(){
    let observable = new Observable(observer=>{
        this.socket.on('user',(user)=>{ 
            console.log(user) // cant log user in here 
            observer.next(user)
        })
    })
    return observable
  }
```

}

App.module

```
 providers: [
    SocketService,
    {

  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (sk: SocketService) => function() {return sk.init()},
  deps: [SocketService],
  multi: true
}],
```

Please explain for me why I can log user in init function but cant in getListUser function. Where is my wrong ? Thank so much

Comment: What's is your backend?